# MySQL - indexing innodb foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, foreign-keys

Is there an improvement in performance in indexing foreign keys in InnoDB? As far as I have [read](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html), InnoDB automatically creates an index for the foreign key.

Here is the query given to me for creating the table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `assignments`;

CREATE TABLE `assignments`
(
    `id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `job` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `created_at` DATETIME,
    `updated_at` DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `job_fk1` (`user`),
    INDEX `job_fk2` (`job`),
    CONSTRAINT `job_fk1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`user`)
        REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `job_fk2`
        FOREIGN KEY (`job`)
        REFERENCES `jobs` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

In there, he created foreign keys named job_fk1 and job_fk2. He used the names of these foreign keys as the name of the index.

Comment: Those indexes probably *are* the automatically created ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there an improvement in performance in indexing foreign keys in InnoDB?

Answer: No. Performance will be degraded due to duplicate keys.

You do not need

```
INDEX `job_fk1` (`user`),
INDEX `job_fk2` (`job`),
```

Those will be automatically created by InnoDB internally. But you need to have index on `users` (`id`) and `jobs` (`id`) for faster operations on `assignments` table

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

"InnoDB requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not exist. (This is in contrast to some older versions, in which indexes had to be created explicitly or the creation of foreign key constraints would fail.) index_name, if given, is used as described previously."

Comment: Primary keys are indexes. Don't need duplicate indexes on those columns either.

Comment: @MarcusAdams: yes, index is not needed on `users` (`id`) and `jobs` (`id`) if they are primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that MySQL will create an index on a column, if it doesn't already exist, when creating a foreign key constraint. However, feel free to create an index on the column and remove the auto-generated one if you want.

You also might want additional multi-column indexes to aid queries like this make-believe one:

```
  SELECT id, user, job
  FROM assignments
  WHERE job = 5
  ORDER BY user
```

The multi-column index `(job, user)` would satisfy both the search and the sort, and since secondary indexes include the primary key, it would also act as a *covering* index in this case.